# How to print nth line after match / empty lines

Tags: sed, awk, scripting

I'm trying to write a short script that finds empty lines and then prints the nth line after the empty lines.

For

```
foo1
foo2
foo3

bar1
bar2
bar3

spam1
spam2
spam3

eggs1
eggs2
eggs3
```

printing every 2nd line after a blank line would result in:

```
foo2
bar2
spam2
eggs2
```

I tried using sed `sed -n -e "/^$/ {N; N; x; N; p; x; d}"` but I cannot get the hold space to be cleared and the result is not what I want.

Comment: You seem to be counting line zero as a blank line when you say "every 2nd line after a blank line."

Comment: @Alexandru Give a try to the **sed** example in my answer. **foo2** cannot be fetched because the example data file does not start with an empty line. There is also a complete solution with **awk**.

Answer (score 8):

```
awk '++n == 2; !NF {n = 0}' < your-file
```

Or:

```
sed -n '
  n;p
  :1
  /./{
    n;b1
  }' < your-file
```

Comment: I love the awk version, simple and elegant. As for the sed one, well, it's cleverly short, but I can't resist being reminded of Djikstra's [Go To statement considered harmful](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Considered_harmful#cite_note-dijkstra1968-2)  ^^

Comment: For readers like me who needs help on the sed one, here is a brief explanation of both: **The awk version is** `both things are done on each lines: Increase n (start at 0) each line, and IF we now have n == 2, print $0 (default action). !NF : is true when there are no fields (ie, line is empty), and in that case: reset n to 0`.   **The 2nd one (sed) is** : `go to next line; print it. Then for each following non-empty lines (ie: at least 1 char): go to next line, and branch on label 1 (thus ignoring those n>2 lines). When condition doesn't match, loop (because of the -n) to the beginning`

Answer (score 1):

You're counting line zero as a blank line, which makes it a bit harder.  If we ignore that and take your literal statement, "print every second line after a blank line", you can do it like so with `ex`:

```
ex -sc 'g/^$/+2p' -cq filename
```

- `-s`: silent mode (`ex` is actually for interactive editing).
- `-c`: state a command to be run
- `g/^$/`: run the following command **g**lobally on all empty lines
- `+2p`: print the line two lines down from the current line
- `q`: the command to quit

To count line 0 as a blank line (but only if line 1 is not a blank line) you have to get fancier; you could do it in `ex` by inserting a blank line before line 1, then filtering lines 1-2 through `uniq`—but at that point you're probably better off using `awk`, for your purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Easily done with `perl`:

```
$ perl -n -e 'BEGIN {$count=0}; 
              if (/^\s*$/) {$count=0} else {$count++};
              if ($count eq 2) {print}' alexandru.txt 
foo2
bar2
spam2
eggs2
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a harcoded value 2 to print each 2nd lines after the empty one.

Give it a try:

```
awk 'BEGIN { empty=1; n=0; } { if ($0 ~ /^$/) { empty=1; n=0; } else if (empty) { n++; if (n==2) { empty=0; print; } } }' file.txt
```

file.txt is the name of the file to parse in the current directory.

It is assumed that there are always n lines or more after each empty lines, when searching for nth one, right?

The test output is below:

```
awk 'BEGIN { empty=1; n=0; } { if ($0 ~ /^$/) { empty=1; n=0; } else if (empty) { n++; if (n==2) { empty=0; print; } } }' file.txt
foo2
bar2
spam2
eggs2
```

### ----

There is a famous page: [Sed - An Introduction and Tutorial by Bruce Barnett](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html)

Give a try to this version below which is very close to yours:

```
sed -n '{
2 {
p
}
/^$/ {n
n
p}}' file.txt

foo2
bar2
spam2
eggs2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use awk to remember the last line that was empty:

```
awk -v gap=2 'BEGIN { lastline=0 } /^$/ { lastline=NR } NR==lastline+gap { print }' test.txt
```

This means:

- In the beginning, set the variable that indicates what the last line was (`lastline`) to zero. This matches your implied requirement that the second line would be printed as if it came after an empty line.
- When in an empty line, set `lastline` to the current line.
- When the current line number is `gap` lines after the last empty lines, print it.

You can set `gap` in the beginning to any number. Note that if there are less than `gap` lines between two empty lines, the first empty line will have no effect.

Answer (score 0):

To print the `lnb`'th line after first blank (empty) line...

Line number to print :

```
lnb=2
```

With sed :

```
sed -ne '/^\s*$/{:a;n;0~'"$lnb"'!ba;p;q}' my_file
```

With perl :

```
perl -ne '/^\s+$/ && $k++;$k!=0 && $k++ && $k=='"$lnb"'+2 && (print,last)' my_file
```